# load to work as append in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am creating form using js functions.. i want that when this function is called twice form should be created twice.. i am using jquery load hence it is overwriting again and again...

my jquery code:

```
function form(module,user) {

    $.post("php/test.php",{ module:module , user:user}, function(data, status){
    var f= jQuery.parseJSON( data );

   $(".cards-container").load("modules/ams.html",function(){
     $(".cards-container > div").addClass("card card-shadow animated fadeInDown");

     $(".form-t").append("<input type='text'"+"placeholder="+f.text+" name='fname' required>");
   });
 });}

form("home",200);form("home",300);
```

**AMS.html:**

```
<div class='w100 large forms'>

        <form action='test.php' method='post'>
            <div class="form-t"></div>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You actually loading the page twice. Seems natural to overwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JQuery** ***load()*** method always replaces content of "element-receiver". Use ***get()*** method to request new content with subsequent appending:

```
var f= jQuery.parseJSON( data );
$.get('modules/ams.html', function(data){ 
  $(".cards-container").append(data);
  $(".cards-container > div").addClass("card card-shadow animated fadeInDown");
  $(".form-t:last").append("<input type='text'"+"placeholder="+f.text+" name='fname' required>");
});
```

Comment: sir i am getting two input boxes, 
this line is called twice 
$(".form-t").append("<input type='text'"+"placeholder="+f.text+" name='fname' required>");


on calling **form("home",300); form("home",400);**

Comment: @rachitsrivastava, yes. That's because `$(".form-t")` selector matches all divs with class `.form-t`. But according to your final plan: we need to append new input field to the last appended div with class `.form-t`. See my updated answer

Comment: to be more clear on calling form("home",300); form("home",400); two cards are created as per need, but the first card contains two input both of  300 and of 400 and second card contains one input of 400

Comment: if I could see your current jquery code and `.cards-container` contents I would give some suggestions, cause I don't see any reasons for such doubling effect for  now

Answer (score 1):

Load will always overwrite. It is a shortcut function for an Ajax method. So instead, use Ajax so you have control of the result:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "modules/ams.html",
    type: "GET"
}).done(function (result) {
    $(".cards-container").append(result);
});
```

This will just append the content directly into the container. You will have to apply any other logic you need. Remember that ids should be unique and forms cannot be nested so make sure you avoid loading html with a form when your container is already within a form.